# Add comma to subprocess stdout

Tags: python

python2.6 - linux - centos6.7
I have a python script that achieves sort of what I want. I use subprocess ,UNIX find and xargs to get a md5sum of multiple files.  I then write this output to a file, the issue that I have is comma delimiting on the space between hash and filename. I have tried splitting with no luck, and also played with the csv module. 
Please suggest:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('--searchpath', action="store", default="~", help="Enter your search path for files", type="string")
parser.add_option('--extension', action="store", default="*.php", help="Enter your file extension", type="string")
options, args = parser.parse_args()

if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 0:
    print "no argument given!"
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

CMD = "/bin/find %s -name *.%s | xargs md5sum" % (options.searchpath,options.extension)
out = subprocess.Popen(CMD,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(out,err) = out.communicate()

fp = open('logfile.txt','wb')
fp.write(out)
fp.close()
```

Please see the output:

```
[root@jr-sandbox python_scripts]# cat logfile.txt
afc69261af7ca0700185e4d9085e7181  /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-11-11-16-57y4XwNP.yumtx
0662322d5529501d09c4cce1371d2db3  /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-11-12-13-438AWQ5C.yumtx
55c04f8add81c667128398cb2f6d258d  /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-11-12-11-26gCDt0O.yumtx
1f7c612e4a00c53bb8ee7a1f0917aaad  /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-10-28-16-149rr0Ad.yumtx
690e3ccf94b75e9960ee3bd2a1f23bce  /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-03-16-13-42SAoXeV.yumtx
```

Desired result:

```
[root@jr-sandbox python_scripts]# cat logfile.txt
afc69261af7ca0700185e4d9085e7181 , /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-11-11-16-57y4XwNP.yumtx
0662322d5529501d09c4cce1371d2db3 , /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-11-12-13-438AWQ5C.yumtx
55c04f8add81c667128398cb2f6d258d , /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-11-12-11-26gCDt0O.yumtx
1f7c612e4a00c53bb8ee7a1f0917aaad , /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-10-28-16-149rr0Ad.yumtx
690e3ccf94b75e9960ee3bd2a1f23bce , /root/python_scripts/testfiles/yum_save_tx-2015-03-16-13-42SAoXeV.yumtx
```

Comment: Not directly helping, but… you know if you used `os.walk` and `hashlib.md5` to do the job yourself instead of calling a script, your code would be shorter, and you would get the output you want easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reload the file in your script
does `.replace(" ", " , ")`

solve the problem?

Comment: Can you kindly show me where that code would go in my script?  I tried:fp = open('logfile.txt','wb')
out.replace(" ", " , ")
fp.write(out)
fp.close()

Comment: One more question, I am getting 2 commas where the space is in my output.  Is there a way to get just one?`code`fp = open('logfile.txt','wb')
fp.write(out.replace(" ",","))
fp.close()
`code`

Comment: Wait... Ok.. You save text with two spaces and out.replace(" ",",") gives two ,'s -> out.replace("  ",",") (two spaces as first argument) probably give one